# Customising Active Admin Filter Return Results in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a model in my app called `Organisation` that has different types, i.e. `Company`, `Group`, etc. Groups are children to a Company, and vice versa. The structure looks something like this:

```
      Company
    _____|_____
   |           |
 Group1      Group2
```

Currently in active admin, for the index page for `Organisation`, I can filter organisations by the individual company, or group - this works fine, no problems.

However what I would like to do is when I search for a `Company`, instead of only returning just that company's information, I would also like it to return and child groups also.

So for example, lets say `McDonalds - Australia` is the company, and it has 2 children `McDonalds - Brisbane` and `McDonalds - Sydney`.

```
       MD-Australia
        _____|_____
       |           |
  MD-Brisbane   MD-Sydney
```

What I would like is for when I filter by `McDonalds - Australia` for it to return `McDonalds - Australia`, BUT ALSO it's children `McDonalds - Brisbane` and `McDonalds - Sydney`.

Is this at all possible under Active Admin?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want the children to be a separate row of the index or just that you want the children of each result to also be printed with their parent?

Comment: Usually searching the parent id will return a table with only one row which is the parent (as it's the only Organisation with the said id). Instead, I would like it to be so that when I search the parent id, it returns the parent as a row, but also the children as individual rows so that I can view all of their data also. i.e. (row 1. parent, row 2. child1, row 3. child2) - hopefully that's clear?

Comment: You can do this but it might be a little tricky the way Ransack builds its queries.  You would need to override the controller method and just handle the filtered case.  I can try to put together a concrete example in a few days when I have more time.  But what I usually do in cases like this is show the index of children below the show page for the resource(parent).  That would be easier to implement and might be clearer for the user.